# Is there a VBA event triggered when a Word document is closed?

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

I'm trying to use `Normal.dotm` as a macro storage object analogous to the `Personal.xlsb` object within Excel.

The built-in [`Document_Close()` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.close(even)) seems like it cannot be triggered unless it's included within a specific document's `ThisDocument` object.

I've also tried to use this [`Application_Quit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.quit(even)) event like so but to no avail:

```
Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Msgbox "closing word"
End Sub
```

Is it possible to listen for closing of the word application like it is in excel with `Auto_Close()`, etc?

---

Attempt for @BigBen based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word)

Class Module **"Event Class Module"**

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application
```

Normal Module **"Module 1"**

```
Dim X As New Class1

Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_Quit()
    MsgBox "closing word"
End Sub
```

Comment: How exactly did you try to implement the `Application_Quit` event?

Comment: @BigBen added my attempt for the mentioned event

Comment: The documentation for that event notes "This code must be placed in a class module, and an instance of the class must be correctly initialized to see this example work; see [Using events with the Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word) for directions on how to accomplish this." I'd start there.

Comment: @BigBen I did notice that but was a little frustrated that I was perhaps missing something else

Comment: @BigBen so would that simply detect when I delete that class if it is spun up instead of word itself, or is it really as simple as putting that into a class module?

Comment: I think that documentation gives you a pretty straightforward walk-through :)

Comment: @BigBen I gave it a good try I thought, but no success (attempt added to question)

Comment: @BigBen's  method working if `Sub App_Quit()` is placed in the class module and `AutoExec` is used in a standard module in `Normal.dotm` to initialize word app at starting of word application like `Dim X As New Class1
Sub AutoExec()
Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub`. Tested OK in 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic ways to capture when any Word document closes:

1. Use a macro named `AutoClose` in any module of Normal.dotm (or any template loaded as an add-in). This is the "old-fashioned" way that comes from the WordBasic (Word 2.0 and 6.0) days.

Note that if any other document (or template) has `AutoClose` that this will over-ride the macro running a "more general" level. In other words, the document- (or template-) specific code takes priority.

```
Sub AutoClose()
  MsgBox "The document " & ActiveDocument.FullName & " is closing."
End Sub
```

2. Work with an application-level event. This requires both a class module and a "plain" module. The event code is in the class module; the code to initialize the class must be in a "plain" module.

This event's name is `DocumentBeforeClose` and *can be cancelled*, both by the user and by code (see the `Cancel` parameter in the event signature).

In contrast to `AutoClose`, if more than one document or template has the event running *all* will fire - there is no priority or "override".

**Class module named clsEvents**

```
Public WithEvents app As Word.Application

Private Sub app_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
  MsgBox "The document " & Doc.FullName & " is being closed."
End Sub
```

**Module**

```
Public myEvents As New clsEvents

Public Sub StartEvents()
    Set myEvents.app = Word.Application
End Sub

Public Sub EndEvents()
    Set myEvents.app = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that if both types of event are present the `AutoClose` fires *after* `DocumentBeforeClose`.

Note also that there is a document-specific event that will fire only for that document: `Document_Close`. This event *must* be in the `ThisDocument` class module of that document.

```
Private Sub Document_Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a pretty frustrating hang up and your write up here is very helpful

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Indeed I could not find this information in a quick search of the site, so I found it important to write up a full description. Glad you asked :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some codes I used to raise an event when the protected Word document is being closed. The purpose is to send a message box BEFORE the preview document is CLOSED. User is able to abort the closing event, modify the document and close the document again. The simpler Word document Document_Close() event handler does not support CANCEL = TRUE.

Step 1. Add following code into a CLASS (codes must be in class module). I named the class as 'EventClassModule', I made a public declaration 'App', these names are referenced in the module.

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

    If vbYes = MsgBox("Do you need to modify the certificate?", vbYesNo) Then
        If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
            ActiveDocument.Unprotect
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Step 2: Add following code into a module. The class name 'EventClassModule' and the public declaration 'App' are referenced here. The code 'Set X.App = Word.Application' will point to the Word application object, and the event procedures in the class module will run when the events occur.

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule

Sub abc()
    Set X.App = Word.Application
    Dim Doc As Word.Document
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    If Doc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        Doc.Unprotect
    End If

    ActiveDocument.Range.Text = Time

    Doc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading

End Sub
```