# Executing on event before print

Tags: vba, events, powerpoint

I want to execute a code which places the username and printer in the footer of a PowerPoint document when the user moves to print the document. The idea is that we can trace the source of rogue printouts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.presentationprint

```
Private Sub App_PresentationPrint(ByVal pres As Presentation)

    Dim slide As Object

    For Each slide In pres.Slides
        pres.slide.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = Environ("username") & " - " & pres.PrintOptions.ActivePrinter
    Next

End Sub
```

The above code executes when placed in a public sub, but not on a print event.

Edit, `Sub Auto_Print()` does not appear to be working either.

Comment: Capturing events in PowerPoint requires setting up an add-in with a class module. This page covers some details and links to a couple of other helpful sites: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm The page to which you linked in your post also has this informative page from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/powerpoint/how-to/use-events-with-the-application-object

Comment: I really like John's advice here and I wanted to supplement the second link he added because it confused me when I first read it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476223/2727437