# AutoClose macro..ending closing action based on answer without save prompt

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with field in the end of the document to update filepath, last saved date & last save by.  I need these to update on the closing of the file.

I am running an Autoclose macro that updates the fields.  The problem is that I need the workbook to save BEFORE these fields are updated, so the last save date and the last save by will update.

I am going to recreate the "Would you like to save changes" message box at the start of the macro, with a yes/no/cancel option. I have 2 questions
1- If  the user says No or Cancel..how do I suppress the system generated Would you like to save to avoid a repeat of the same question (or pass along  their response to my version of the question to the system so they don't see it)
2 - If the pick cancel, how do I stop the system action of closing the file?

What i have below I found online , the sendkeys (ESC) is not stopping the system close.`

```
Sub AutoClose()

'if the document is already saved
If ActiveDocument.Saved = True Then
'update all fields, save, close without prompt
Else
'which would be the document's status is not saved
answer = MsgBox("Yes No Cancel Example", vbYesNoCancel)
'above is do you want to save


  If answer = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Yes"
  ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
    'dont save, dont update, close file without prompt
  Else
    'this is the cancel, so dont update, dont close
    ActiveDocument.Saved = True
    SendKeys "{ESC}"
    
  End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your AutoClose called in `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel as Boolean)`?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what that means.  The AutoClose I am using is the build in AutoClose...where could I see those details?

Comment: @Notus_Panda Without wanting to place too fine a point on it, Workbook_BeforeClose is an ***Excel*** event - this is  ***Word*** question.

Comment: Deleted my comment as to not confuse others, my recommending link was this however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467191/is-there-a-vba-event-triggered-when-a-word-document-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub AutoClose()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rslt
With ActiveDocument
  If .Saved = True Then
    Call UpdateFields
    .Save
  Else
    Rslt = MsgBox("Save changes and close, or discard changes and close?", vbYesNoCancel)
    If Rslt = vbYes Then
      Call UpdateFields
      .Save
    ElseIf Rslt = vbNo Then
      .Saved = True
    Else
      Call UpdateFields
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateFields()
With ActiveDocument
  .Fields.Update
  .PrintPreview
  .ClosePrintPreview
End With
End Sub
```